# How to add a list inside MultiPartRequest using dart?

Tags: list, api, flutter, dart, multipart

I have multiple fields to send in my multipartrequest but i didn't recognize how can i include a list within the sent data .. i have two lists that i want to send (nationalities and languages) ,

This is my code:

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest('Put', uri);
request.fields['id']="07bb2a17-7cd5-471b-973a-4b77d239b6c3";
request.fields['username']="beeso";
request.fields['email']="jake-username2@gmail.com";
request.fields['password']="jake123-";
request.fields["oldPassword"]="jake124-";
request.fields["gender"]="Male";
request.fields["dateOfBirth"]=DateTime.now().toString();
request.fields["name"]="dsjnss";
request.fields["languages"]=["Language1","Language2"].toString();
request.fields["nationalities"]=["Nationality1","Nationality2"].toString();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then if the languages and nationality are in String format then you can use he List and then add them accordingly in it and later pass the list to it, or if it is kind go object then you can add it in the List. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi sagar , i didn't understand what you mean.. there's no explicit way (ready method) to append a list to the multipartrequest. How can i achieve this?